# Exclude Child Categories Using wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );

$child_cats = (array) get_term_children( $category , 'category' );

wp_list_categories( array(
        'exclude'  => $child_cats
    ) );
```

Is it possible to exclude all child categories?

Update : I tried this also but it doesn't work.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
        'childless'  => true,
    ) );

    $child_cats = (array) get_term_children( $categories, 'category' );

    $cats = wp_list_categories( array(
        'exclude' => $child_cats
    ) );
```

Edit 2 : I preferably would like this to work with [get_the_category_list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list)

Comment: `child_cats` is missing `$`, so replace `child_cats` with `$child_cats` and see if it works then.

Comment: Turn DEBUG on and you'll get interesting data.

Comment: Nothing interesting when debug set to true.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of excluding child categories, try to get only categories that have no parents (0)

```
    $cats = wp_list_categories( array(
        'parent' => 0
    ) );
```

That should work with no issues.

EDIT: `get_the_category_list()` does not support advanced arguments. Your best bet is [wp_get_post_categories($post_id, array('parent=>0'))](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/). That will return an array of objects, you have to do the HTML yourself with a foreach loop.

Comment: Close but the problem with this is it returns all categories. I only need it to return the parent category the post is assigned to. It half works. See edit 2.

Comment: Use the better `wp_get_post_categories`

Answer (score -1):

using this code

```
function rk_fix_tax_queries_on_archives( $query ) {
    // Only run this on the main query for the category archive
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // What category is this
        $cat = $query->query_vars['category_name'];
        // Build the new query args
        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'category',
                'field'            => 'slug',
                'terms'            => $cat,
                'include_children' => false,
            ),
        );
        // Set the new query args to $query->query_vars['tax_query']
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        // Setting the query args is not enough, we have to create a new tax query object
        // and force feed it to the query
        $query->tax_query = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_tax_query', 'rk_fix_tax_queries_on_archives' );
```

Comment: This question relates to categories each single post is assigned to. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839121/exclude-wordpress-category-from-get-the-category-list